# Android - fragments/custom views and layout width/height

Tags: android

When I create a layout for my fragment or my custom view I must define `layout_width` and `layout_height`. When I use this fragment or view in another layout, I must also define `layout_width` and `layout_height`.

Let's say that the root element of my fragment/view layout has `layout_height="match_parent"` and when I use this in another layout I have for example `<fragment layout_height="wrap_content"`.

In this case the `layout_height` element is basically defined twice, once in the layout of the fragment/view itself and once in the layout where I'm using it, but with different values.

What happens to the value of `layout_height` of the root element of the fragment/view in this case? I don't understand how this works... does one override the other?

Answer (score 0):

when you are using match_parent for parent layout it matches the parent width/height.Now when you are using another layout inside this parent layout
1.if you are setting wrap_content it will not totally use the height/width of parent as it's set to wrap_content
2.setting child layout width/height to match_parent then the child layout will  stretch to entire parent limits

Comment: I know. But lets say I have a fragment with a layout that has `layout_height="match_parent"`. And I have **another** layout file where I use this fragment, and that `<fragment>` element has `layout_height="wrap_content"`. My question is what happens to the value of `layout_height` in this case, as it is basically defined **twice** for the same view, but with **different** values.

Comment: I think it will not occupy the entire space